# Regular expression for matching incomplete tags in the form $tagname$

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a small templating system in javascrip, where the user can put tags in the form **$tagname$**. I can match all tags with the patter: **/\$\w+\$/**.

Also, I want to match incomplete tags specifically (it would start with **$** and finish with a word boundary that is not **$**). I can't use **/\$\w+\b/** because $ is also a word boundary (so it will also match correct tags). I tried with this but it does not work: **/\$\w+[^\$]/**.

It matches the incomplete tag in this string "word **$tag** any word", but it also matches this "word **$tag$** any word".

What is the correct ending for that regular expresion?

Comment: when I read until "..incomplete tags" i felt an impulsive urge to quote bobince's reply on "how (not) to parse html with regex" :D

Comment: haha I remembered that as I was posting the question too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match incomplete tags specifically, you can use a negative lookahead:

```
\$\w+(?![$\w])
```

But it's probably more efficient to use Tomalak's regex and do a separate check to see if it ends with `$`.  Or capture the (optional) ending `$` like this:

```
\$\w+\b(\$?)
```

If group #1 contains an empty string, it's an incomplete tag.

Comment: I was not clear enough that I wanted to match incomplete tags specifically, so this did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
\$\w+\b\$?
```

Your try `\$\w+[^\$]` does not work because `[^\$]` *must* match something, while `\$?` matches optionally. Well, and because you did not define where the word boundary is.

Besides, escaping the `$` in a character class is not strictly necessary, this is the same thing: `[^$]`.

Answer (score 0):

So, if $ is treated as a word boundary, why not just do: `\$\w+\b`?  Otherwise, just use `\$\w+[\$\b]`, I guess, even though that would be redundant.

Comment: `\$\w+[\$\b]` won't work; in a character class, `\b` matches a backspace, not a word boundary.